# Can a subscriber also publish/send message in NServiceBus?

Tags: nservicebus, subscriber

Is the communication bi-directional in [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/)?

a subscriber can also publish/send message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NServiceBus does indeed support bi-directional communication, a subscriber can publish messages as well. Configure it as a publisher as per-usual, write handlers for events coming from other publishers, configure the messages in the UnicastBusConfig, and you're done.

Comment: if subscriber publish messages, only the subscriber's publisher will get the message?

Comment: Is NServiceBus suitable for this scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437456/communication-framework-recommendation?

Comment: The fact that a given subscriber S1 also publishes messages has no effects on the original publisher P1. If subscriber S2 is subscribed to the messages that S1 publishes, it doesn't care that S1 is subscribed to P1.

Comment: @Udi Dahan : Can you elaborate your answer, i'm trying to use NServiceBus with 4 Windows Service whose have to act both as Publisher and Subscribers to communicate between all these 4 applications.

Comment: Yoann, the comments here aren't a great place for elaboration. I suggest you post your question to the discussion group: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/