# Communication framework recommendation

Tags: wcf

I have two applications, and one is keeping sending live images to the other and it need to be long-running.

1. WCF - is it suitable?
2. TCP/IP directly?
3. Service bus, NServiceBus?

Is there any better alternative for this communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NServiceBus is indeed suitable for that, as it sounds like you would like non-blocking communication between them. If your images are larger than 3-4 MB, you may need to do some additional steps to get it working with NServiceBus as the built-in MSMQ transport doesn't support messages larger than 4MB.